# Copy someone else Patent

Tags: wo1996038643a1

How could the goverment grant this patent number w0199603864a1,when  Rodney M McGee Sr. invented this in patent number 4858456 in 1988.

Comment: It seems the US goverment don't mind giving  a patent to big companys,that someone else has allready patent..

Comment: Not correct - W0199603864a1 is not a granted patent.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer to the question is **No patent has been granted**.

The document you are referring to, W0199603864a1 is not a granted patent. It is not even a U.S. national patent application at this point. Documents starting with WO are international PCT (Patent Cooperation Treaty) applications. I have not compared the substance of the two documents but any new application should not ultimately issue as a patent unless its claims define something new and non-obvious.

Sometimes a claim is written so specifically and narrowly that while it is different than what was was done in the past, but nobody cares. A very narrow claim can generally be gotten around easily. The claim 1 in W0199603864a1 is one of the longest claims I have seen and may be in that category.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i'm the  one who did the McGee patent and I know Chicago lock Co. tried to  patent it after I did.Also cam lock from over seas came to  america and started making the  lock..I also did two patents in one,to try and  block this  type of  action.

McGee